# visual studio 2010 auto change .csproj file

Tags: visual-studio

I meet a strange problem when I use visual studio 2010. I have many projects in my solutions. When I add a folder in my solution(in visual studio, not windows explorer), it automatically changes some projects in the solution, i.e, the .csproj file. Basically, it changes the name of some projects it references. For example,

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Common\Common.csproj">
  <Project>{EXXXXX-XXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX}</Project>
  <Name>Common</Name>
</ProjectREference>
```

is changed to

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Common\Common.csproj">
  <Project>{EXXXXX-XXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX}</Project>
  <Name>Common %28Common\Common%29</Name>
</ProjectREference>
```

That is, it adds something to the name. but it only changes one or two project name it references, not all the projects it references. BTW, I only added a folder to the root of the solution. It's totally irrelevant to other projects in the solution.

Although this is not a big problem, it doesn't affect compiling and execution of the program, it's quite annoying. Anyone knows what causes this problem?